# Docker django Import Error : No module named 'social'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker, python-social-auth

I am new to **Docker+Django** development environment. I am facing difficulties in adding `python-social-auth` into my project.

Following is the configurations in workspace:

**requirement.txt**

```
Django==1.9
psycopg2==2.6
python-social-auth==0.2.14
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .
    .
    'home',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
]
```

And when trying to run `migrate` command as follows:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate
```

getting following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'social'
```

Following is the content in **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Following is the details coming when running command `pip3 freeze` in `Docker Quickstart Terminal`

```
defusedxml==0.4.1
Django==1.9
django-social-auth==0.7.22
httplib2==0.9.2
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauthlib==1.0.3
psycopg2==2.6
pygame==1.9.2a0
PyJWT==1.4.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-social-auth==0.2.14
python3-openid==3.0.9
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.0
six==1.10.0
wheel==0.26.0
```

**UPDATE LOGS**
Following is the errors logged while running command `docker-compose up`:

```
Starting project_db_1
Starting project_web_1
Attaching to project_db_1, project_web_1
db_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-02-03 11:26:56 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
web_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1 |   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1 |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
web_1 |     utility.execute()
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
web_1 |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
web_1 |     commands = get_commands()
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
web_1 |     for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
web_1 |     self.check_apps_ready()
web_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
web_1 |     raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
web_1 | django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
project_web_1 exited with code 1
```

many many thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: `pip freeze` shows django-social-auth, even though it's not listed in your `requirements.txt`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini First I thought to use `django-social-auth` and later changed to `python-social-auth`, thats why in `requirements.txt` not able to see the `django-social-auth` informations.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: can you show the latest `requirements.txt`, with the latest `pip freeze`, with the latest exception, removing all outdated information?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini : above what ever I have give is same only. Nothing is changed.

Comment: I have removed and killed, all the images and containers, using docker command and trying to run `docker-compose up`, thats not working.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, you have two problems here. `AppRegistryNotReady` occurs because you forgot to call `django.setup()`. About `ImportError`: check your `sys.path`

Comment: before trying to include the `python-social-auth` into project, it was working fine. Do I have to call  `django.setup()` then!!!

Comment: Let's focus on the `ImportError` first. What is your `sys.path`? Does it include the path to `python-social-auth`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102481/discussion-between-dipak-chandran-p-and-andrea-corbellini).